# Electron Angular Library error

Tags: angular, electron

I'm working with Angular and Electron to try few things. I've setup everything and the standard project generated with cli and launched with electron works fine.

Then I added few things, and here's what I have so far.

script & style from angular.cli

```
 "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "styles.css",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
    ],
```

main component.ts

```
import * as toastr from 'toastr';

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { toBase64String } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/source_map';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    constructor() {
        toastr.error('Helllo world!');
    }
}
```

the html basic, just for try if bootstrap works :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>
        Electron App
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button routerLink="/customers">Customers</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button routerLink="/orders">Orders</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button routerLink="">Home</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I managed to let toastr works with the include at the top of my component.ts. If I serve this with a classic 'ng s' it works fine. But if I try to launch it with electron running the script "ng build && electron ." I see the app running fine, but in console showing me the error :

```
bootstrap.bundle.js:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at setTransitionEndSupport (bootstrap.bundle.js:121)
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:199
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:201
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:9
    at bootstrap.bundle.js:10
```

As far as I've read Angular6 doesn't exports the modules(?) I believe. So does anyone know how to solve this?

- - - - EDIT / SOLVED(?) - - - -

Ok so I've kinda figured out the problems. What I've done :

1) Changed the bootstrap version to 4.0.0 in package.json file (then removed the package-lock.json file, rm -rf node_modules and reinstalled the modules with npn i).
2) edited the tsconfig file in this way :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "toastr"
    ]
  }
}
```

3) Edited the component in this way :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { toBase64String } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/source_map';
declare const toastr: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    constructor() {
        toastr.success('Helllo world!');
    }
}
```

4) Added this in the head of the index.html

```
 <script>
    if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
      window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    }
  </script>
```

This solved my problem I can now wrap my app with electron perfectly and use it with a ng serve.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug of bootstrap 4 beta 2.

That will be fixed with next release.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24439

Let's upgrade your version